# Inverse Laplace Transform of $\frac{2s+5}{s^2+4s+13} $ (Check My Solution)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

I have solved, just need someone to check my solution is correct.

My answer is -

$$2e^{-2t}\cos(3t) + \dfrac{1}{3} e^{-2t}\sin(3t)$$

Thanks

Comment: What prevents you to compute the Laplace transform of this function to check this is the answer?

Comment: I have computed it, just wanted to make double sure.

Comment: Then show your work (as always...).

Comment: Any other time I would but I'm very short on time and it takes a while to type the entire solution out properly in TeX.

Comment: Sorry @Did, I don't wanna be rude but I wanna answer this question. **YES** Finance, your answer is correct. :)

Comment: @Tunk-Fey Thank you very much.

Comment: @upvoters How is this question (with its answer now...) useful to the site?